# File uploading with PHP

Tags: php

Alright so I've got some problems with my file upload, for some reason it is saying that I am using invalid file type (I am trying to upload a simple JPEG picture)

Heres the HMTL I've made for it

```
<div id="popup_FileUpload_bg">
    <div id="inner_fillUpload">
        <form action="image-upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>Tekst na slici</label><br/>
            <input id="txt_uploadCustom" name="customFileText" type="text" placeholder="Text..." /><br/><br/>

            <label>Tip postera</label><br/>
            <select name="selectVal">
                <option value="on_pic">Na slici</option>
                <option value="bellow_pic">Ispod slike</option>
                <option value="above_pic">Iznad slike</option>
                <option value="bellow_and_above">Iznad i ispod slike</option>
            </select><br/><br/>

            <label>Kliknite ispod da bi ste ubacili poster</label><br/>
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" required><br/><br/>
            <input id="submitFileUploadCustom" type="submit" value="Postavite poster" name="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the PHP itself

```
require_once "assets/core/user.php";

use app\user\control as user_c;

if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
$fileNAME = substr(hash('sha512',basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])."_".time()),0,10); //I think that this is the problem...
$target_dir = "assets/img/user_uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $fileNAME;
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Fajl je preveliki";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Nedozvoljeni tip fajla, mozete ubaciti JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF kao poster sliku";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "<br/>Sorry, your file was not uploaded. "."FILE NAME: ".$fileNAME."<br/> FILE TYPE: ".$imageFileType." <br/> TARGET: ".$target_file;
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name'], "assets/img/profiles/".$_SESSION['username'].".".$imageFileType)) {

        //Just adding stuff to MySQL
        $user = new user_c();

        $user->submitUserUpload($_SESSION['username'], $fileNAME, $_POST['customFileText'], $_POST['selectVal'], $imageFileType);

    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

I've tried debugging the results and this is what I got
Sorry, your file was not uploaded.

> FILE NAME: 58a0fc9cc0 FILE TYPE:  TARGET:
>   assets/img/user_uploads/58a0fc9cc0

Comment: Take a look at my answer. My answer explains that output. It's taking the sub-string of a hash value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at

```
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" )
```

and then  look at

```
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

and then

```
$target_file = $target_dir . $fileNAME;
```

and $filename is

```
$fileNAME = substr(hash('sha512',basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])."_".time()),0,10); //I think that this is the problem...
```

So ... in moment where  "if"  is  fired  up there is no extension in file name ,  so "if"  always  give you false .

try to change

```
$imageFileType = pathinfo($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: This is not secure. The 'name' element is user input. You should not start off just using it. At minimum, filter and validate it first.

Comment: Is that safe to do?  The name element is user input, right?

Answer (score 2):

Some tips.

### Sessions

Doing good, but you can do better.

```
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
} elseif (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_regenerate_id();
} else {
    throw new \RuntimeException('The PHP session did not start.');
}
```

### Security

You should integrate [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) into your algorithm and much earlier. Also, be aware that you may want to use [multi-byte string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) (mb_*) to process filenames. Be wary of NULL-bytes and [NULL-byte injection](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246949/Null%20Byte%20Injectionhttp://) (\0, etc ....).

At minimum, attempt to make a basic filename filter.

```
private function fileNameFilter($string)
{
    return trim(basename(trim(str_ireplace(['U+0000', '\x00', '\x0', '%00', '\0', 'U+0025', '%25', '%', 'U+000D', "%0a", "\r", 'U+000A', "%0d", "\n", '#', '%2f', '/', '%2f%2f%2e', '../', '%2f%2e', './', ' '],
                                                ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
                                                trim(stripslashes(trim(strip_tags(trim(basename($string))))))))));
}
```

### File Type Validation

You are starting validation too late.
You do this first with the file name:

```
basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])
```

Instead, ***filter*** and ***validate*** the `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]` element first. Do this as a separate process before attempting to use any of its values. What if the file name is too long and an obvious hack! Do *not* trust user input.

First, your algorithm immediately attempts to get the trailing name component of a file path, then tacks on and underscore and the current time:

```
basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])."_".time()

// /dir/dir/dir/file.jgp just became file.jpg._191919032450 , etc ...
```

Next, you apply hashing algorithm to obtain a digest:

```
hash('sha512',basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])."_".time())

//Now, it's 909ujgt43j8534mi349gv5n-934m5uiui53n34-9m9mu-u9
```

Finally, you take a sub-string of the hash. This is one place you may want to consider making sure what your character encoding is and such. Remember, there is always [mb_substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php). Try *testing* it with both versions of substr().

```
$fileNAME = substr(hash('sha512',basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])."_".time()),0,10);

// Now, it is i40tl502l-
```

By this time, `pathinfo()` cannot give you the output you want.

```
$target_dir = "assets/img/user_uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $fileNAME;
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //Not going to work.
```

Other techniques for determining the file type include opening the file and inspecting it. Do a search on Stackoverflow for good answers on validating an uploaded file.

---

### Validation Ideas (incomplete):

Here is one part (just one part) of the validation I do on the $_FILES superglobal with `filter_var_array()`.  I sanitize the user input elements before I get to this point. My process is rather robust, but I think I am making my point.

```
//Blacklisting Regular Expression.
private $nameRegex    = '/(?>\A[0-9A-Za-z-_]{1,250}?\.[A-Za-z]{1,4}\z){1}?/u';
private $typeRegex    = '/(?>\A[a-z]{1,20}\/[0-9A-Za-z.-]{1,50}\z){1}?/u';
private $tmpNameRegex = '/(?>\A[\/\\A-Za-z:_-]{2,255}\z){1}?/u';

public function setNamedPHPFilterInstructions()
{
    foreach (array_keys($this->filteredInputArray) as $file) {
        $this->phpFieldValidationArray[$file]['error']    = ['filter'  => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                                                             'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                                                             'options' => ['min_range' => 0, 'max_range' => 0]];

        $this->phpFieldValidationArray[$file]['size']     = ['filter'  => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                                                             'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                                                             'options' => ['min_range' => $this->fileProps[$file]['minSize'], 'max_range' => $this->fileProps[$file]['maxSize']]];

        $this->phpFieldValidationArray[$file]['type']     = ['filter'  => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, 
                                                             'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR, 
                                                             'options' => ['regexp' => $this->typeRegex]];

        $this->phpFieldValidationArray[$file]['name']     = ['filter'  => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, 
                                                             'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR, 
                                                             'options' => ['regexp' => $this->nameRegex]];

        $this->phpFieldValidationArray[$file]['tmp_name'] = ['filter'  => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, 
                                                             'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR, 
                                                             'options' => ['regexp' => $this->tmpNameRegex]];
    }

    return;
}
```

Other ideas for validation include.

```
private function hasGoodErrorCodes()
{
    $errorCodes = [];

    //Gather submitted error codes.
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $properties) {
        $errorCodes[] = $properties['error'];
    }

    //Compare error codes accordingly.
    foreach ($errorCodes as $value) {
        if (!(($value >= UPLOAD_ERR_OK) && ($value <= UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION) && ($value !== 5))) {  //There is no 5 error code.
            throw new SecurityException('Invalid file upload error code!');
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private function hasGoodFileSizes()
{
    $fileSizes  = [];
    $fileLimits = [];

    //Gather submitted file sizes.
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $properties) {
        $fileSizes[$file] = $properties['size'];
    }

    //Gather pre-established file size limits.
    foreach ($this->maxControlCharsArray as $file => $limit) {
        $fileLimits[$file] = $limit['size'];
    }

    //Compare submitted file sizes to their associated size limits.
    foreach ($fileSizes as $file => $size) {
       if (!($size <= $fileLimits[$file])) {
            throw new SecurityException('An uploaded file exceeds upload limits!');
       }
    }

    return true;
}

private function hasGoodMimeTypeLengths()
{
    $mimeTypeLengths = [];
    $mimeTypeLimits = [];

    //Gather submitted mime type lengths.
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $properties) {
        $mimeTypeLengths[$file] = mb_strlen($properties['type'], 'UTF-8');
    }

    //Gather pre-established mime type length limits.
    foreach ($this->maxControlCharsArray as $file => $limits) {
        $mimeTypeLimits[$file] = $limits['type'];
    }

    //Compare submitted mime type lengths to their associated limits.
    foreach ($mimeTypeLengths as $file => $length) {
       if (!($length === $mimeTypeLimits[$file])) {
            throw new SecurityException('Mime type length exceeds limits!');
       }
    }

    return true;
}
```